# HtmlUnitDriver to invoke local html file

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, htmlunit-driver

I am trying to invoke a locally stored html file using the get() method of the HtmlUnitDriver, but the page is not getting loaded. I tried to get the page source and I got 404 not found as the response. If I use the chrome driver in headless mode I am able to invoke the file. Is it possible to do this using HtmlUnitDriver?

Below is a code snippet

```java
HtmlUnitDriver unitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

public class Test {

  public void clickOn() {
    String filePath =
            "home/test-output/100071234.html";
    try {
      unitDriver.get(filePath);
      WebElement ele = unitDriver.findElement(By.id("submitPayment"));
      ele.click();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the code that causes issue

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open local file you have to adhere the URI format. So for Linux it would be (if `home` folder is under the root folder):

```java
String filePath =
            "file:///home/test-output/100071234.html";
```

Here you can find other examples (Windows, Mac OS): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: I used the same format,but it does not seem to work. The same code works fine if the driver instance is of type ChromeDriver class.